# Django: how to publish an app

Tags: python, django, apache, production, linode

I have developed an app using Django 1.1.1 and python 2.7.1. I want to publish it on a commercial website, but not sure which one.
the app works fine on the apache server running on my local machine, however, before investing on a host, I want to be sure that I have the necessary requirements, so if it matters, what are the possible hosts I can use?
I use Apache 2.2 with python 2.7.1 on my local machine running with Django 1.1.1. I use the Windows OS. I tried looking at linode but they don't have a documentation for Windows users in using Django and mod_wsgi, so does it even matter?

This is the first time I try to publish on a commercial site, so I don't want to invest on a host and then find myself stuck and not knowing how to upload my Django app.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the docs on linode just fine, it doesn't matter that you're a Windows user, the app will be deployed on a linux box.

You can also try a shared hosting solution, that will run django right way, without any need to configure and setup a new machine. My personal recommendation is http://www.webfaction.com/ . Another alternative is https://www.djangy.com/.

Comment: I would also recommend http://www.webfaction.com/ for Django apps. They've hosted my site for over a year now, and I've been really impressed with their easy-to-use setup tools and customer service.

Comment: I am also using webfaction and find it really easy to use.